# logging but I need it to alert

Tags: javascript

This finds the info I want but logs it rather than alerting.  This was my best guess on how to do that since console.log worked (in place of alert) to log it.  Sorry for the simple questions!

processSplicedValue(collegeFriends, 1, alert)

Comment: what does the code of processSplicedValue() look like?

Comment: I'm learning about callbacks.  It logs 1 collegeFriend that was spliced from the array, which is what I want, but I want it to alert rather than log. Do you need to see more?